# beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin, repository

Errors for **repository** and **service**:

```
Error creating bean with name 'rimeService' defined in file [...]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
Error creating bean with name 'rimeRepository': Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
```

**RimeService**:

```
@Service
class RimeService(private val repository: RimeRepository) {
    fun findRimes(character: String) = repository.findByCharactersContains(character)
}
```

**RimeRepository**:

```
@Repository
interface RimeRepository: JpaRepository<Rime, Int> {
    fun findByCharactersContains(character: String): List<Rime>
}
```

**Controller**:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rimes")
class RimeController(private val service: RimeService) {

    @GetMapping("/{character}")
    fun getByCharacter(@PathVariable character: String) = service.findRimes(character)
}
```

**dependencies**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
//  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}
```

In addition, the class and methods in controller is grayed out in Intelij, which means those are never used.

Please let me know if there's anything wrong with my configuration.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception thrown when using @Service in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174036/exception-thrown-when-using-service-in-kotlin)

Comment: @MadhuBhat That works. Thanks for helping!